# Implementation of Matlab's uicontrol in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to run the .m Matlab code of a graphics program used in our lab in Octave. Octave tells me there is no definition of the function "uicontrol", which is used in the code.

After some searching, I read that the package JHandles has an implementation of the "uicontrol" GUI function. However, I can't find jhandles anywhere. Therefore:

1. Can someone tell me how to get the jhandles package and get it running in my copy of Octave, installed in Mac OS X 10.6?

OR

2. Is there another implementation of "uicontrol" in another library/package in Octave?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently looking for the same thing.
Only found the following so far:
-jhandles (available from the octave sourceforge page apparently): http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/FAQ.html#MATLAB-compatibility
-octawrap: http://octawrap.sourceforge.net/

Haven't tested any of them yet.

Comment: Tried jhandles, lots of functions in my code didn't work. Will try octawrap, thanks for the tip!