# Uicontrol on Octave 3.6.2

Tags: octave

I am trying to port a script from Matlab to Octave. The one function that I miss is uicontrol(), for displaying togglebuttons and pushbuttons.

On SO there is this question: [Implementation of Matlab's uicontrol in Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3516747/1284631)
 At that time, uicontrol() was not implemented in Octave, but since 3.6.N, it is advertised as being implemented: http://www.octave.org/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_are_the_developers_planning_to_replace_Gnuplot_with_an_OpenGL_backend.3F

However, after installing octave 3.6.2 on Ubuntu Quantal, I have this error:

```
octave:1> uicontrol
ans=-1.8402
error: __go_draw_figure__: unknown object class, uicontrol
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/private/__go_draw_figure__.m at line 181, column 15
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/__gnuplot_drawnow__.m at line 86, column 5
```

However, the /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/uicontrol.m is existing.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the MSVC/win32 version of Octave 3.6.2; this comes with QtHandles, it works with uicontrol (tested only with basic widgets - buttons, textboxes).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I ended using the same. There are several bugs in Octave, that I will report there. For example, QtHandles does seems to not correctly report the current mouse coordinates for the root object and for the current axes. All the while, the current mouse coordinates are correctly reported for figure objects. Thanks for your answer, please look for further information this thread here: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Uicontrol-not-displaying-anything-td4631686.html.

Comment: This is the version of Octave 3.6.2 that I ended using: http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.2%20for%20Windows%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/

Comment: +1 for mentioning QtHandles, with the mention that they are only available in the Visual Studio-compiled binary version of Octave, and not in the GCC-compiled binary version. Although that could be arranged through re-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself (at least partially), for those we may encounter the same problem: Octave 3.6 introduces a new graphics toolkit, namely FLTK, along with the default one, the Gnuplot. The installed graphics toolkits are visible with:

```
octave> available_graphics_toolkits
```

command. The graphic toolkit currently in use is given by:

```
octave> graphics_toolkit
```

The default is: "gnuplot". Or, the uicontrols are not compatible with gnuplot, but with FLTK. So, before calling the uicontrol function, one should switch to the FLTK graphics toolkit, with the following command:

```
octave> graphics_toolkit fltk;
```

before calling the uicontrol function.

However, this answer is only partial: although with the FLTK graphics toolkit, uicontrol seems to work without fault and even returns a valid handler (allowing setting and getting its properties), the actual pushbutton is not visible on the figure... So, another: Any help?

Thank you.